# Needs to download big file in chunks

Tags: java, rest, file, spring-boot

I have 20 MB of the file. I just want to download the file in the browser in chunks/streams so that If there is another request it is not blocked for a long period of time.

I also see the pause behavior in a long file. It is not needed right now. If someone can explain this because of my curiosity to know how it works.

I have the file saved in DB. When I get the request to download the file. I will get the file from DB. I push the byte code in the response body and send it to the browser. In the browser, I have created one link and download the file in one go.

Back-end code:

```
  @GetMapping("/job-detail/{jobExecutionId}/file-detail")
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFileDetail(@PathVariable final Long jobExecutionId) {
    final FileDetailDto fileDetailDto =
        fileTaskletService.getFileDetailByExecutionId(jobExecutionId);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(new MediaType("text", "csv"))
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=\"" + fileDetailDto.getFileName() + "\"")
        .body(new ByteArrayResource(fileDetailDto.getData()));
  }
```

I wants to download the file in chunks so that other requests can also start the downloading on the same time.

Comment: do not store `blob` file in `db` instead use filesystem

Comment: @emotionlessbananas I don't think that will help OP's requirements.

Comment: Okay, After that, it is possible to download the file in chunks.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I am just suggesting

Comment: Why wouldn't they be able to download the same file. Different request, different thread, different resources. Looks like you are trying to fix a problem you don't actually have.

Comment: I think your server framework should handle that out of the box.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Different people on different machines requested to get the same file. Now if one request download the whole file first then the second request will wait until the first request is completed

Comment: That normally doesn't happen. So I suspect something else going on that is blocking this. By default there are 200 request handling threads, so you should, theoretically, be able to download the file with 200 users at once. I suspect rather a db lock or something else locking the download.

Answer (score 2):

From the wording of your question it sounds like you want the server framework to set the following header for you so that the data flows back in chunked blocks:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

To do that you need to supply a Spring resource where the full size is not known in advance. You have used `ByteArrayResource` where the full size *is* known and results in a `Content-Length` header being set in the response and chunked is not used.

Change your code to use `InputStreamResource` and the service will stream the response back to the client with a chunked transfer encoding and no content length. Here's a sample (syntax unchecked):

```
try(ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileDetailDto.getData())) {
  return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(new MediaType("text", "csv"))
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
              "attachment; filename=\"" + fileDetailDto.getFileName() + "\"")
          .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));
}
```

While this will get you a chunked response I'm not convinced it's the root of your problems with the browser because they are all very capable of asynchronously streaming back data regardless of how the server provides it.

Comment: Perfect as it does not create an intermediate copy of the data. Ideally a compression `GZipOutputStream` (text.csv.gz) would reduce the size enormously (< 2MB). This could be done invisibly when the browser request offers this capability. But that is an additional step.

Comment: @AndyBrown Issue is not to reduce the size of the current request, The issue is to download the data on the browser in chunks so that multiple users can hit to download the file. Could you please let me know the solution explained above also download the file in chunks. Suppose I have to download the file of 200mb. I wants that multiple users can hit at the same time.

Comment: @JoopEggen could you please look into the above comment.

Comment: As _multicast_ is not for HTTP (but UDP) as for browsers, [**HLS**](https://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/What-Is-.../What-is-HLS-(HTTP-Live-Streaming)-78221.aspx) is probably what you intend. A huge effort. **Chunks**, transfer in pieces, is _- I think -_ just for unkown data content lengths. I would check how good the data is compressed; movies evidently not so.

Comment: You mean to say, right now it is not possible in HTTP so the better option is to reduce the file size.

Comment: If your files are prohibitively large and you have potentially lots of users accessing them at the same time then cache them on a medium that supports streamed access (e.g. your file system) and return `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>`. Implement `StreamingResponseBody` to do an NIO file transfer from disk to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: I have a binary file of size close to 100 MB, will i be able to download without time-out issues with this approach of using InputStreamResource ? (am not planning to cache in cdn or anywhere to prevent unauthorized file download)